# newly added books from PC don't show up in Kindle

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

I have some issues with my paperwhite 5 and I need some help.

I was able to use it for months wo any issue.
I copied many books from PC into Kindle's "documents" folder (in mobi format) - all was nicely visible.
After one occasion - when I created an additional sub-folder within "documents" and moved some files there from "documents" - I cannot see any newly added files anymore. Even though I do exactly the same as before, Kindle don't show any new books anywhere - no matter ho i setup visibility (all/documents/downloads)
Furthermore, if i delete any book from Kindle via PC, Kindle still shows the book and when I open it, it says "it has been removed".
So it seems, it doesn't refresh itself at all.

What i tried already:

- restart
- deleting books / adding new books
- adding books into "documents" folder, and "documents/downloads" folder
- different visibility setup on Kindle (all/documents/downloads)

Please can anyone help what should I do to get back my lovely kindle.
I have many new books which I can't read, and it drives me crazy.
Thanks for your support!

Comment: Rather than copy books to a folder, use a tool such as Calibre (https://calibre-ebook.com/) which can *index*, as well as *copy* them on the ereader.